Flask Blueprint with socketio configuration
My problem 
I have a Flask app that I recently separated into blueprints as it grew in size.
All of the app migrated well except for one thing - socketio.
My goal is to have a socketio background task run in on my server, but to have all of it's configuration in a separate blueprint.
I can't figure out how to use the main app's socketio instance start_background_task() inside of another blueprint.
So far I ran into 2 main issues:

I tried to tell blueprint.py to import main.py's socketio, and also tell main.py to import blueprint.py. That results in the expected circular import error.
After that I searched online for a configuration of some sort and the only config I found https://github.com/miguelgrinberg/Flask-SocketIO-Chat), suggested creating socketio in a separate file, and then importing it by both main.py and blueprint.py to avoid the last error.
But this always raised an issue where blueprint.py tried to use socketio before it has initialized.
(This is also what ChatGPT suggested).

It's crazy how little information I was able to find about this...
If anyone ran into this before I'd appreciate any help I can get!
Code and extra details 
Everything runs on -
python 3.10.12
Flask 2.2.5
Flask-SocketIO 5.3.6

File structure -
.
└── backend/
    ├── app/
    │   ├── blueprints/
    │   │   └── sockets/
    │   │       ├── __init__.py
    │   │       └── events.py
    │   └── __init__.py
    └── main.py

sockets/init.py -
from flask import Blueprint

sockets_bp = Blueprint('sockets_bp', __name__)

from . import events

sockets/events.py -
from ... import socketio

# This Actually works
@socketio.on('Hello')
def hello():
    print("Got a message!!")


def fetch_recent_logs():
    logs = [1, 2, 3]
    return logs

def emit_logs():
    print('Emiting logs to client')

    try:
        while True:
            recent_logs = fetch_recent_logs(db_handler)
            
            socketio.emit('new_log', {'data': recent_logs})

            socketio.sleep(5)
    except Exception as e:
        print(f"Error fetching/emitting logs: {str(e)}")

# Raises 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'start_background_task'
socketio.start_background_task(emit_logs)

app/init.py (create_app) -
from flask import Flask
from flask_socketio import SocketIO
from flask_cors import CORS
import os

socketio = SocketIO()

def create_app(debug=False):
    app = Flask(__name__)

    app.debug = debug
    app.config['SECRET_KEY'] = os.urandom(24)

    CORS(app, supports_credentials=True, resources={r"/*": {"origins": "*"}})

    from app.blueprints.sockets import sockets_bp
    app.register_blueprint(sockets_bp)

    socketio.init_app(app, cors_allowed_origins="*")    

    return app

And finally, main.py -
from app import create_app, socketio

app = create_app(debug=True)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    socketio.run(app, host="0.0.0.0", port=5000,  debug=True, allow_unsafe_werkzeug=True) 

Hope that helps!!

The example that you linked in #2 works fine. If you tried to structure your application following that example and you are getting errors, please include the specific errors in your question.

Hey Miguel, In every forum I saw you're always there helping people out, so thanks a lot!
I tried restructuring everything again, this time following your example more carefully but this error still seems to stay -> 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'start_background_task'.
This only happens when I try to start a background task as basic @socketio.on() does actually work great.
Do I need to configure it differently somehow?
(I can add my code and everything to the question if that helps)

Please update Python 3.12.6 and will solve your problem. Or wait until October 10 for Python 3.14.0

Hey! I tried updating, But even when running on a python:3.12.6-slim docker image I still get the same error...
Are you sure that it's a version problem?

@GuyShalom The error is likely a logic bug in your application. Without seeing the code it is impossible for me to help.

@MiguelGrinberg I added the code to my original answer, as well as other details. If there's anything else you may want to see, please feel free to ask!

I managed to fix it, 
My solution was instead of trying to start_background_task inside the blueprint on its initiation, I now start the task inside create_app(), giving up on the idea on initializing everything inside the blueprint.
The main difference from before is that now all of my configuration is in a separate file. By importing my threaded function into create_app() and then passing socketio back to it as a parameter, I'm avoiding all on the circular imports and initiation issues.
This also makes it pretty much pointless to create a blueprint for the sockets as just a regular .py works.
Thanks to everyone that helped!! 
The code:
create_app() -
from flask import Flask
from flask_socketio import SocketIO
import os

from flask_app.sockets.background_tasks import emit_logs

socketio = SocketIO()

def create_app(debug=False):
    app = Flask(__name__)

    app.debug = debug
    app.config['SECRET_KEY'] = os.urandom(24)

    # Initialize SocketIO.
    socketio.init_app(app, cors_allowed_origins="*")    

    # Start background tasks.
    socketio.start_background_task(emit_logs, socketio)

    return app

background_tasks.py -
# Threaded function to emit logs to client
# Now takes a socketio object!!!
def emit_logs(socketio: SocketIO):
    print('Emitting logs to FE')
    db_handler = database_handler()
    db_handler.connect()

    try:
        while True:
            recent_logs = [1, 2, 3]

            socketio.emit('new_log', {'data': recent_logs})

            socketio.sleep(5)  # Fetch and emit every 1 seconds
    except Exception as e:
        print(f"Error fetching/emitting logs: {str(e)}")
    finally:
        db_handler.disconnect()

* Edit‼️
With this configuration, using socketio normally (by importing it from create_app), causes a circular import.
To prevent this, in sockets/events I defined an 'initialize_socketio()' function that waits until create_app() passes the socketio instance to it as a parameter, and then uses it to configure the events:
from flask_socketio import SocketIO

# This is ran in create_app() to initialize socketio's events.
def initialize_socketio(socketio: SocketIO):

    @socketio.on("test_socket")
    def test_socket():
        print("Got a message!")

And then call it in create_app() -
from flask import Flask
from flask_socketio import SocketIO

from flask_app.blueprints.sockets.events import initialize_socketio

socketio = SocketIO()

def create_app(debug=False):
    # Initializing Flask
    app = Flask(__name__)

    # Initialize SocketIO.
    socketio.init_app(app, cors_allowed_origins="*")     
    initialize_socketio(socketio)

Hope that helps!!
